# Trying to pass local jar to maven install

Tags: java, maven, jar

I'm trying to do a `mvn install` with my local jar.

Here is the pom file, [Allure cli](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cli/blob/master/pom.xml).

I want to use the `allure-report-builder` jar from my local machine, rather than from the maven repo. So I tried this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=allure-report-builder.jar -DgroupId=ru.yandex.qatools.allure -DartifactId=allure-report-builder -Dversion=2.1 -Dpackaging=jar install
```

Here `allure-report-builder.jar` is my local jar, in the current directory. But it doesn't seems to be working properly. The resulting jar is still using the jar from maven repo.

Where I'm making mistake?

Comment: try giving some different artifact and groupid to your jar and install it again

Comment: It doesnt work either.Changing the artifact id and passing the same in console, is giving me compilation errors

Comment: @Kirti: But any chance, do I need to remove the dependency tag in pom.xml for which I'm passing local jar?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your procedure of adding local jar as maven dependency...are you using eclipse... or i can tell u the procedure how to do it.coz it works for me everytime

Comment: @Kirti: Not eclipse, using command prompt. By running `mvn` command. Yes kindly say me the procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do two different things at once:

`install:install-file -Dfile=allure-report-builder.jar -DgroupId=ru.yandex.qatools.allure -DartifactId=allure-report-builder -Dversion=2.1 -Dpackaging=jar`

and

`install`

The first one is called a standalone goal. This will just install the file.
The second is called a phase, in this case the `install` phase. This will run every project-task/goal up until the install, which includes testing and compiling.
Depending on what you want, the first will always work. The second suggest that you have code to compile, but that you don't have all the required dependencies yet. If this is all fixed, you just run `mvn install` to get this jar in your local repository.

Comment: So your saying first I need to run the `install:install-file -Dfile=allure-report-builder.jar -DgroupId=ru.yandex.qatools.allure -DartifactId=allure-report-builder -Dversion=2.1 -Dpackaging=jar` first and then `install`?

Comment: No I want to use the local jar ( which I'm using in my first step ) as a dependency jar to the `mvn install`, locally! So that no maven repo downloading is required.

Comment: let me rephrase: if you have the sources, you should do it with `mvn install`. If you only have a jar (we call it a third party jar), you should use `install:install-file`.

Comment: So your saying, when I call `install:install-file` it will put my local jar in the maven repo (local) and then if I run `mvn install`, the local jar which is put in the first step will be used, right?

Comment: No, both `install` and `install:install-file` do the same thing: copying a jar to your local repository. The difference is how you got this jar. If you downloaded it from somewhere, you can only use `install:install-file`. However, if the jar is a result of your own sources (by calling `mvn package`) then the next phase is `install`, which will copy your `target/someProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` to your local repository.